# How do i animate on mouse over in Elm-UI?

Tags: animation, elm, elm-ui

I would like a simple wipe when hovering over a button. I figured out to use `mouseOver` to change the background on hover, but I am not sure how to create a wipe from one background to another.
I am aware of [elm-simple-animation](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/andrewMacmurray/elm-simple-animation/latest/#hook-into-elm-ui), but I am too new to Elm to understand the docs..

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is surprisingly involved and part of it is I suspect that a proper transition library specifically designed around elm-ui is (AFAICT) still missing.

The basics steps are like this:

1. Define properties for the start and mouseOver states.
2. Figure out which properties these correspond to in elm-simple-animation.
3. Add a transition for those.

```
Element.Input.button
    [ Background.color (Element.rgb 0.5 0.5 0.6)
    , Element.mouseOver
        [ Background.color (Element.rgb 0.7 0.7 1)
        ]
    , Transition.properties
        [ Transition.backgroundColor 500 []
        ]
        |> Element.htmlAttribute
    ]
    { onPress = Nothing
    , label = Element.text "Hello"
    }
```

You can see a working example [here](https://ellie-app.com/cRdW7fvjfTKa1).

Comment: Perfect answer thanks!
Just adding this link to help people with step 2
https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/andrewMacmurray/elm-simple-animation/latest/Simple-Transition